# React state management - Rerenders with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok so to explain my problem in short. I was following a rock-paper-scissors tutorial, but when I finished it, I started implementing stuff on my own. I am not new to React, but I also have a lot to learn still. I want to completely understand state management. A quick explanation:

This is a rock-paper-scissors game, where the user can click on buttons which represent the rock, paper and scissors, and the same button that gets the user input, also generates random computer choice from those 3. (handleClick func)

I then have a useEffect that compares the user and computer choice, and then increase user or computer points by 1, to whoever won that round. When the points from either one of them reach 5, the game ends and a restart button shows up.

And now my problem:

When I add the conditional logic in the useEffect that sees if anyone of them reached 5 points, my click is always 1 behind. Im setting a state for the game over, which is false on the app load, and gets set to true, when the condition is met. So in this case it will reach 5, but the restart button itself is gonna show up on the next click.

BUT, if I add the logic to the JSX instead, without using state, the restart button shows on round 5 exactly, which is the correct way.

Now, I researched quite a lot, and I know that setState is async, and it will be evaluated on the next render.. but I don’t get why it does that if I put it in the useEffect, which also has the dependency array, which will trigger a rerender if the state changes. Even when I put the 'gameOver' in the dependacy array, it still doesnt work

I am missing some key info to put the whole puzzle in place.

You can find the code here, its not very long.

https://www.codepile.net/pile/6PO6m8GN

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to trigger a rerender, you can use dependency array of useEffect. So, if you want to trigger useEffect when computer or user point changes, add them inside your useEffect  dependency array.

This guy explains it perfectly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dH6i3GurZW8&t=1106s

Comment: If you add user points to thedependacy array, it will cause infinte loop, so I added another useEffect with the logic for the restart button, and then added the computer and user points in the dependancy array, and it worked.

Comment: I didn't realize that you put increase of points inside use effect(then it is normal that it has infinite loop) for your game, normally you dont even need useEffect. if you put your entire evaluation inside handleclick, it works perfectly fine. see the link https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-darkness-ve9tcq?file=/src/App.js
the reason it works because react starts a re-render when state changes as well.

Comment: Aha ! Thanks, that explains a lot of confusion.